# Recursive function - count number of even numbers in tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I must count the number of pairs in a tuple. I can´t use while or for. It must be a recursive function. The outcome I must have is, for example:

```
count_pairs((4, 5, 6))   
2
count_pairs(())
()
count_pairs((3, 5, 7))
0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def count_pairs(t):
    if len(t) == 0:
        return ()
    elif t[0] % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + count_pairs(t[1:])
    else:
        return count_pairs(t[1:])
```

My difficulty is how can I return () if an empty tuple is given to me. Because every outcome I have is (). Something's not right. Can you please help me? I'm a beginner in Python. Thank you

Comment: So "pair" here means "even number"?

Comment: yes, sorry my english

Comment: @glibdud "pair" is French for "even"

Comment: The base case should return 0, not an empty tuple

Comment: `1 + count_pairs(t[1:])` this will throw error anyways. Not sure what you are trying to do but above code should be changed to `(1,)+ count_pairs(t[1:])`

Comment: Ok, i understand, so the outcome should be count_pairs(()) -> 0

Comment: @DeepSpace No, as the OP wants the empty case to return an empty tuple

Comment: @KellyBaptista Well it depends, is that what you want? The code can be written either way, but in your examples, you say that you want an empty tuple as the output for an empty tuple. If you give desired functionality, surely you should stick to it?

Comment: Is that an HW assignment? Having a function that sometimes returns a number and sometimes an empty tuple is a very good way to produce "wtf" moments in production.

Comment: I just checked with the teacher and I must return 0, so sorry for waisting your time!

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, I pointed this out in my answer :)

Comment: @JoeIddon thanks for the answer. I learn so much more here then reading books.  Thank you everyone for explaning the logic of this to me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to write this is to store the result of your current element (the first element of `t`) in a variable (`this`) and the result of counting pairs (even elements) in another variable (`rest`). Then if `rest` has a "truthy value" (it is not an empty tuple), then you can return the `0` or `1` for this element to it; otherwise you just return this digit and don't concatenate the two.

That is to say,

```
def count_pairs(t):
    if len(t) == 0:
        return ()
    rest = count_pairs(t[1:])
    this = t[0] % 2 == 0
    return this + rest if rest else this
```

works fine:

```
>>> count_pairs((4, 5, 6))
2
>>> count_pairs(())
()
>>> count_pairs((3, 5, 7))
0
```

---

However as you elude to in the comments, it does in fact make sense to return `0` for the empty tuple, rather than another empty tuple. This is for the reason that a function should generally return the same data type (it is not forced in Python to make your code more flexible, but it definitely is a requirement in other languages).

The code also becomes neater if you do it that way:

```
def count_pairs(t):
    if len(t) == 0:
        return 0
    return (t[0] % 2 == 0) + count_pairs(t[1:])
```

which now behaves in, what I would consider to be, a more natural way:

```
>>> count_pairs((4, 5, 6))
2
>>> count_pairs(())
0
>>> count_pairs((3, 5, 7))
0
```

---

*Footnote*

I'd just like to point out that the statement `t[0] % 2 == 0` is equivalent to `1 if t[0] % 2 == 0 else 0`, because `1` is equivalent to `True` and `0` to `False`, in Python. This makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

in python2

```
def count_pairs(tup):
    if len(tup) == 0:
        return ()
    elif len(tup) == 1:
        return (tup[0] + 1) % 2
    else:
        return ((tup[0] + 1) % 2) + count_pairs(tup[1:])
```